# Finding an implied userID from an XML-based search in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Sorry for the length of this post, but I need to explain the situation properly in the hope of getting the best advice.

Our application is a corporate portal where administrators can post news items to users globally in the company.  Some are visible to everyone, but others are only visible to specific individuals. The user hierarchy is as follows:

```
[tbl_Country].[Id]
    └ [tbl_Sites].[Id]
          └ [tbl_Department].[Id]
                └ [tbl_Users].[UserId]
```

A user exists in a single department, that exists in  a single site, etc.
When a news item is posted, historically the broadcaster selects the users it applies to from a series of dropdown lists.  A many-to-many table captures `UserId` values against `AnnouncementId` values, so when a user logs in, they see the relevant news items.

However, due to a massive increase in staff, and constant transfers of staff between locations, the current method of managing visibility is too time-consuming.  So, an alternative approach is being considered whereby each news item is given a visibility value based in XML, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO [tbl_NewsItems] 
    (newsItem, visibleTo) 
VALUES
    ('A new policy has been issued, read it here',
     '<applicableTo>
       <sites>
         <s id=2 />
         <s id=54 />
       </sites>
       <departments>
         <d id=542 /> 
       </departments>
     </applicableTo>');
```

Each news item is then made applicable to selected users by location (with the ability to mix and match).  Based on `[tbl_NewsItems]` containing many items, all relevant for different groups of people, what approach would be suitable for, when a user logs in, finding all the relevant announcements just for them?

I've been reading on how this might be done, and have thought of two options:

1. Comparing the UserId, DepartmentId, SiteId, CountryId values directly against each news item's XML using [XQuery](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/the-xml-methods-in-sql-server/).  This looks quick and simple, but perhaps limited in case the user structure changes
2. Using [OUTER APPLY](http://sqlwithmanoj.com/2012/01/03/using-cross-apply-outer-apply-operators-with-udfs-derived-tables-xml-data/) and create a function that returns a table of relevant userIds for each news item, filtered appropriately.  This seems more complex and could return huge lists of users, but quite robust

Can anyone recommend their approach, or has anyone achieved the same please?

Comment: I could not advice using SQL tables for storing structured data as XML. Did you consider parsing the XML into the relational table when inserting the new announcements?

Comment: In the end you need to know what announcements are related to what users, so I would keep that many-to-many table. There should be smart user interface to configure visibility of the announcement, but the end result is that many-to-many relationship. The interface doesn't have to show this level of details, it may allow to make bulk selections, like the whole department or site, or any combination of countries, sites, departments, users. There can be several variants of the interface for several most common cases, but end result is always the same: list of user IDs vs announcement IDs.

Comment: @Vladimir, that's the very problem.  People are moving about across the organisation, new people coming, leavers leaving.  The userId vs announcementId relationship is constantly changing and needs to be kept up to date.  Its too big a job to do manually.  The interface already allows whole countries, sites or departments to be selected.  That's how the XML is being generated.  It's just how this is mapped in SQL which is causing the problem...

Comment: @GerardoLima yes but I was unsure whether that's the best approach.  Department is the lowest structure above User, so perhaps I should parse the XML into a AnnouncementId/DepartmentId table, and use that.  It would be easier to update if the announcement was changed, and would avoid the UserId management being required

Comment: Well, it really depends on the life-time of the announcement and what it applies to. If announcements are related to Departments, then have a many-to-many table with Departments instead of Users. I would see what is static in your situation and what is changing and model it accordingly. I would not try to store XML in the database in any case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using XML column for structured data which is meant to be dealt by SQL Server will most likely cause performance problems and make your code harder to read. Parsing the XML on input will save you from performance issues and keep the XML to SQL code localized. The following code is a simplification for getting the sites for a department from both XML and a standard SQL table, to picture the differences in code -- the second would be easier to maintain.

```
-- using XML structured data
-- @xmlData can be stored into a column, the local variable is just for brevity
DECLARE @xmlData AS XML = N'<applicableTo>
       <sites>
         <s id="2" />
         <s id="54" />
       </sites>
       <departments>
         <d id="542" /> 
       </departments>
     </applicableTo>';

SELECT mysite.value('@id','int') [site_id]
, mydepartment.value('@id','int') [department_id]
FROM @xmlData.nodes('//applicableTo/sites/s')               AS mysites(mysite)
CROSS APPLY @xmlData.nodes('//applicableTo/departments/d')  AS mydepartments(mydepartment)

-- standard SQL
SELECT [site_id]
FROM site_to_department
WHERE [department_id] = @my_department_id;
```

Comment: Thanks Gerardo.  The reason for XML is that DepartmentId 542 may not be located at SiteId 2 or SiteId 54, it may be a department somewhere else, even a single department in another country.  Hence, the XML allowed the pick-and-choose method of specifying where the announcement gets posted.  I don't know if that affects your decision/answer?

Comment: Hi, @EvilDr, actually, the XML is just a mean to present this information. It can be presented in many ways (think JSON, CSV or anything else), but on SGBDs the natural way it to use a table. If you have a given data-source on XML, i'd suggest you to use a simple ETL process to import to your database and then stick to standard SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your `Announcement` table to add additional fields related to

```
[tbl_Country].[Id]
[tbl_Sites].[Id]
[tbl_Department].[Id]
```

So your `Announcement` table would now have a structure

```
AnnouncementId CountryID SiteID DepartmentID UserID
```

With each field allowing nulls except `AnnouncementId`.

In your case the records would be

```
AnnouncementId CountryID SiteID DepartmentID UserID
1              2         NULL   NULL         NULL
1              54        NULL   NULL         NULL
1              NULL      542    NULL         NULL
```

When a user logs in, you can identify the users `CountryID`, `SiteID` and `DepartmentID` and then filter on this table as below

```
SELECT * FROM Announcement
WHERE CountryID = @CountryID
    OR SiteID = @SiteID
    OR DepartmentID = @DepartmentID
    OR UserID = @UserID
```

For UI, you can use XML to send this data to sql server and then populate this table from your xml.